# Getting error java.lang.NoSuchMethodError when call android function in unity3d?

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, gradle

My steps:
(1) In unity3d I add codes bellow:

```
AndroidJavaClass jc = new 
AndroidJavaClass("com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer");
AndroidJavaObject jo = jc.GetStatic<AndroidJavaObject>("currentActivity");
jo.Call("Pay", "key");
```

(2) Export Unity3d project to Gradle(New), and i get a gradle project including activity files:

- UnityPlayerActivity.java
- UnityPlayerNativeActivity.java
- UnityPlayerProxyActivity.java

In AndroidManifest.xml, the main activity is:

```
android:name="com.fs.game.UnityPlayerActivity"
```

(3) I add a Pay function in file UnityPlayerActivity.java:

```
public void Pay(String key)
{
    // test
}
```

(4) At last, use `gradlew build` to build this project, and install the apk in my cellphone.
But when I click the test button, I get error:

> java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:no non-static method with name = 'Pay'
>   signature='(Ljava/lang/String;)V' in class
>   Lcom.fs.game.UnityPlayerActivity;

Where is the problem?

Comment: `Pay` method should be static to call view Class name.

Comment: If Pay method is static, and the AndroidJavaObject should call like this: jo.CallStatic("Pay", "key"); ?

Answer (score 1):

I think your code is correct.
You build it with gradle, and gradle has a plugin **Proguard** by default.
Proguard is used to shrink or obfuscate code, so your method name maybe changed by obfuscation.

You should either:

1> edit **build.gradle** to disable proguard

2> modify txt file used by Proguard(e.g. proguard-android.txt, proguard-unity.txt), add **keep** rules to keep your class not obfuscated.

Comment: Yep, I change "minifyEnabled"&"useProguard " to false, and not it does work! 

 release {
    minifyEnabled false
    useProguard false
     proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-unity.txt'
     signingConfig signingConfigs.release
    }

Comment: did you know if i want proguard enable then how to solve this issue